# Jmeter junit not on sampler menu

Tags: jmeter, junit3

I've donwloaded JMeter 3.1 and am trying to run a junit sampler.

Per these instructions
jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf
I've added a ThreadGroup to test plan, i select add->sampler, but do not find Junit.

This is what I see.  What am I missing?
[no jmeter on menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gydXA.png)

Here is an example photo I found on the tutorial.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzPTc.jpg)

I do have a junit class in a jar in the lib/junit folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, my JMeter 3.1 (installation comes with the JUnit Request sampler out of the box.

[image: JMeter JUnit]

So please double check the following:

1. *jmeter.log* file - normally it contains enough information to guess the problem cause
2. you should have `ApacheJMeter_junit.jar` file under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation. If it is not there - most probably something went wrong and your installation is corrupt

Be aware that you can add JUnit support (as well as any other JMeter Plugin) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager JUnit]

Answer (score 0):

For JMeter 5.0, the JUnit sampler did not appear for me when I incorrectly placed all my JUnit dependency jars in JMeter's lib/junit. It looks like it got stuck parsing all those jars looking for tests.

After placing JUnit dependency jars in JMeter lib folder and only the unit test jar in lib/junit, it worked correctly and JMeter GUI also started a lot faster.

> I do have a junit class in a jar in the lib/junit folder.

This may be the problem in you case, if JMeter does not find any tests (or fails to find in my case), the JUnit sampler is simply not added to the UI